# Is it necessary to use underscore (_) variable inside functions in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

The variable/function name starts with underscore "_" means that it is a private variable/function in Dart language. It is well-known.

What if the underscore variable is used inside a function?

Is it necessary to use declare an underscored variable in a function(not in a class) to denote that the variable is only used in the function? or as it is self-evident that the declared variable can only be used in the function so that using underscore prefix is just a redundant thing? (or for the naming convention?) (when the function does not have any inner-function)

With underscore:

```
void sample() {
 var _something = getSomething();
 doSomethingWith(_something);
 //use _something
}
```

Without underscore:

```
void sample() {
 var something = getSomething();
 doSomethingWith(something);
 //use something
}
```

Plus, is there any performance-related difference between them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What if the underscore variable is used inside a function?

[Dart's official style guide expressly advises against doing that](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style) (emphasis mine):

> There is no concept of “private” for local variables, parameters, or library prefixes. When one of those has a name that starts with an underscore, it sends a confusing signal to the reader. **To avoid that, don’t use leading underscores in those names**.

As for the other question in your post:

> Is it necessary to use declare an underscored variable in a function(not in a class) to denote that the variable is only used in the function?

No, all variables declared inside a function are naturally limited in-scope to that function. Adding an annotation to say a local is "private" is both redundant and incorrect (as locals aren't "private" because locals aren't shared).

```
void sample() {
 var _something = getSomething();
 doSomethingWith(_something);
 //use _something
}
```

In this example, `_something` is not actually "shared" because `doSomethingWith` is *passed a copy* of `_something`: it doesn't have a *reference* or pointer to `_something`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast and exemplary answer with a nice official link.

Answer (score 0):

**Dai** is right about almost everything but I want to correct him. Primitives (like int, bool, and num) are passed by value. Objects are passed by reference. So `doSomethingWith` will have reference to `_something` if `_something` is not a primitive
But it doesn't change the answer. You don't need to underscore variables in methods.

Comment: Dart uses reference-passed-by-value. Dart doesn’t support “true” (I.e. C++-style) references nor can you pass-by-ref in Dart either, annoyingly. (This QA refers to Java, but the same concept applies to Dart: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/159145 )